# Cofinite topology - what's the flaw in this argument?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space, where $T$ is the cofinite topology (if $U \in T$, then $X\backslash U$ is finite).

Let $S \subset X$, where $S$ is infinite. I think that $\overline{S} = X$, but I'm wondering where the logic fails if one argues like the following:

Since $\overline{S}$ is closed, we have that $X\backslash \overline{S}$ is open, which implies $X\backslash(X\backslash \overline{S})$ is finite. If $\overline{S} = X$, then $X \backslash \overline{S} = \emptyset$, which implies $X\backslash(X\backslash \overline{S}) = X\backslash\emptyset = X$, which is infinite, since S is infinite. So doesn't this contradict the fact that $X\backslash(X\backslash \overline{S})$ is finite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you’re overlooking is that $\varnothing$ is by definition a member of **every** topology, so if $T$ is the cofinite topology, $U\in T$ if and only if **either** $X\setminus U$ is finite **or** $U=\varnothing$.